# How To Remove One Element From a Class with Lots Of Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `.note` and I want to be able to click on `.remove` (which is in each `.note`) and it will remove the `.note` that the `.remove` that I clicked was in.  I've used `.closest()` to do that, but it will only work for the first note, and not the other ones after that.  Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

The code that removes the `.note`:

```
$('.remove').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.note').remove(".note");
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrp">
         <h1>Click to make a new note!!!</h1>

        <hr>
        <div class="note">
            <p class="remove"><b>X</b>

            </p>
            <div class="time"></div>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="item"></textarea>
            <div class="saved"><span class="msg"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('.note').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
});

$('#wrp, #wrapper').click(function showNote() {
$('.note').fadeIn();
});

$(function () {

$(document).mousedown(function (event) {
    // only proceed if clcik is not anywhere in a note element
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.note').length) {
        var note2 = $('.note').first();
        note2.clone().insertBefore(note2);
        console.log(note2);
    }
});
});

$('.remove').click(function () {
$(this).closest('.note').remove(".note");
});



window.onload = function () {
var input = $("#item").focus();
};



function date() { //code indentation
var now = new Date();
now2 = now.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + now.getDate() + '/' + now.getFullYear() + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
$('.time').html(now2);
}
date();

var autosaveOn = false;

function myAutosavedTextbox_onTextChanged() {
if (!autosaveOn) {
    autosaveOn = true;
    $('.item').everyTime("3000", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/echo/html/",
            data: "id=1",
            success: function (msg) {
                $('.msg').text(Saved);
                alert("saved");
            }
        });
    }); //closing tag
}
}
$(".note").closest('.note').draggable();

$(function () {
$("#tabs").autoSave(callback, ms);
});
$(".item").autoSave(function () {
var time = new Date().getTime();
$("#msg").text("Draft Autosaved " + time);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you know that your `.remove` element is a direct child of the `.note`, you can just select its parent:

```
$('.remove').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

if the `.remove` element is NOT a direct child of the `.note`, you can do this:

```
$('.remove').click(function () {
    $(this).parents(".note").remove();
});
```

**IMPORTANT:**

if your notes are generated dynamically, then you will need to utilize event delegation, by attaching the click handler to the wrapper instead of the `.remove` buttons, and fire when elements with class `.remove` are clicked inside the wrapper:

```
$('#wrapper').on("click",".remove",function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have one note and then you are cloning it when you click on something other than the note and inserting it next to the previous note. Since you are only binding to the first note you need to use a live function. E.g. something like

```js
 $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
   $(this).closest('.note').remove(); 
 });
```

Comment: forgot to add the closing bracket stuff.. Should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$('.remove').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.note').remove();
});
```

That will remove only the `closest` note, as the `closest()` function already selects the elements anyway. If you pass a parameter to `remove()` it will search for all elements that match it, but if you use it on an already selected node, it will remove that node.

DOCS: https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: I already have this in my code, and it will only delete the first note, and won't work for all the other notes

Comment: Ah I see. It's a duplication issue (like the other answer describes). As you are cloning nodes, the clicks are still wrongly targeted to the original element. Apply it to every target. Give the other guy a one up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. Possibly I am late... got distracted while typing the answer.

```js
$('.remove').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrp">
         <h1>Click to make a new note!!!</h1>

        <hr>
        <div class="note">
            <p class="remove"><b>X</b>

            </p>
            <div class="time"></div>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="item">Note1</textarea>
            <div class="saved">
              <span class="msg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="note">
            <p class="remove"><b>X</b>

            </p>
            <div class="time"></div>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="item">Note2</textarea>
            <div class="saved">
              <span class="msg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="note">
            <p class="remove"><b>X</b>

            </p>
            <div class="time"></div>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="item">Note3</textarea>
            <div class="saved">
              <span class="msg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="note">
            <p class="remove"><b>X</b>

            </p>
            <div class="time"></div>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="item">Note4</textarea>
            <div class="saved">
              <span class="msg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="note">
            <p class="remove"><b>X</b>

            </p>
            <div class="time"></div>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="item">Note5</textarea>
            <div class="saved">
              <span class="msg"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```